# access Class variable from within a function

Tags: angular, typescript, class, variables, scope

I have the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import keypress from 'keypress.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  debug: boolean = true;
  tenInchScreen: Boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    var listener = new keypress.Listener();
    listener.register_many([{ // 1 key
      "keys": "f1",
      "prevent_default": true,
      "on_keyup": function () {
        if (this.debug) {
          console.debug("F1 key pressed");
        }
      },
    },
  ]);

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I would like the `"on_keyup"` function to be able to access the `debug` variable in the `HomeComponent` class.  When I hit "F1" on my keyboard, the console gives me this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined

How do I access `debug` from that function?

Comment: Change `function () {` to `() => {`.

Comment: @R.Richards that's the ticket.  Thank you.  Can you explain the reasoning real quick please?

Comment: See the link for the duplicate post. This is a common question.